# What does it mean when a second patent number is listed in the application events?

Tags: publication

I'm looking at the patent, US20070010755A1, "Monitoring of the cerebral state of a subject"

https://patents.google.com/patent/US20070010755A1/en

The patent in question lists the following events:

```
Application US11/176,944 events 
2005-07-07  Application filed by General Electric Co
2005-07-07  Priority to US11/176,944
2005-09-01  Assigned to THE GENERAL ELECTRIC COMPANY
2007-01-11  Publication of US20070010755A1
2010-08-24  Application granted
2010-08-24  Publication of US7783343B2
2010-10-25  Assigned to GENERAL ELECTRIC COMPANY
Status
Active
2028-11-17  Adjusted expiration
```

I can't find US7783343B2 anywhere.  Does anyone know what the second publication means?

Comment: Your linked document is an application, not a patent. Google Patents has the granted patent: https://patents.google.com/patent/US7783343B2/en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US7783343B2 is the publication number of the granted patent and I can find it when using EPOs Espacenet: https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/037619152/publication/US7783343B2?q=US7783343B2

The first publication number is the publication number of the patent application.

Comment: Thanks @BrittRosendahl, I'm still a bit confused.  Is this correct --> they filed in 2005, published their filing application in 2007 and in 2010 their patent was published?

Comment: Yes those are the dates. In the US patent system an application gets a number at the time of filing, then at the 18 month point the application is published *by the USPTO* (there are exceptions) under a different number from a different sequence based on the year of publication. If granted and issued  the patent itself is made public and give a patent number that is its place in the sequence of all US patents ever granted. And the particular patent number in the question is readily findable in google patents as well as Espacenet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Thanks for the answer.